# I am getting an error : 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pcap

I am capturing a packet from the network and trying to parser it into my python program and display the source MAC, destination MAC and Protocol each packet in it consists of.

Error occurred in last line: "print("Protocol:",str[protocol],"Time to live:",str[timetolive])"

My code:

```
#!usr/bin/python

import pcapy

from struct import*

pcap_file=pcapy.open_offline("single.pcap")

count=1

while count:
    print("Packet #:",count)

    count=count+1
    (header,payload)=pcap_file.next()

    l2hdr=payload[:14]
    l2data=unpack("!6s6sH",l2hdr)

    srcmac="%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:" %(ord(l2hdr[0]),ord(l2hdr[1]),ord(l2hdr[2]),ord(l2hdr[3]),ord(l2hdr[4]),ord(l2hdr[5]))
    dstmac="%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:" %(ord(l2hdr[6]),ord(l2hdr[7]),ord(l2hdr[8]),ord(l2hdr[9]),ord(l2hdr[10]),ord(l2hdr[11]))

    print("source MAC:",srcmac,"Destination MAC:",dstmac)

    ipheader=unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s',payload[14:34])
    timetolive=ipheader[5]
    protocol=ipheader[6]

    print("Protocol:",str[protocol],"Time to live:",str[timetolive])
```

Comment: Please elaborate and style the code bit into code style

Comment: @AlexFung I am capturing a packet from the network and trying to parser it into my python program and display the source MAC, destination MAC and Protocol each packet in it consists of..... However this is the complete code that I have written:

Comment: @PrashuPratik please include what you said in the comment in your question as well.also, fix the code tag.

Comment: The captured file is saved by name "single.pcap".... l2hdr is for the layer 2 header, l2data is the data in a packet.... I have used the "pcapy" module in this code.

Comment: @PrashuPratik include traceback including line where error occured

Comment: @sideffect0 Yes done that... can you please tell me how to rectify the error?

Comment: It's helpful to include the full traceback, which includes the line number. Without we'd need to run the code to know which line the error originates from.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the general mistake that I had made in the code. However, I am getting another struct.error in line "   l2data=unpack("!6s6sH",l2hdr)   " .....the error states that "unpack requires a string argument of length 14" ......What should I change the value from 6s6sH to, to make the length 14? @PaulRooney

Answer (score 2):

Seeems like you are using `[]` instead of `()` for `str` function,

use `str(protocol)`, `str(timetolive)`; check [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), modify code to `str(protocol.encode())`, `str(timetolive.encode())` for python3 compatibility.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the general mistake that I had made in the code. However, I am getting another struct.error in line "   l2data=unpack("!6s6sH",l2hdr)   " .....the error states that "unpack requires a string argument of length 14" ......What should I change the value from 6s6sH to, to make the length 14? @sideffect0

Comment: @PrashuPratik include this in question so that others can answer or create another question

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
print("Protocol:",str(protocol),"Time to live:",str(timetolive))
```

You are trying to access the `str` function with square brackets, which isn't going to work.